# Fedora 29 ARM on raspberry pi3b+ cannot connect to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, raspberry-pi

After a seemingly successfull install and `dnf update -y  && reboot`, I try to connect to my wifi router with

```
nmcli dev wifi connect 'mywifirouter' password 'password'
```

...I get

```
Error: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).
```

more from /var/log/messages (courtesy rsyslog package)

```
Feb 14 14:18:31 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171911.7750] ifcfg-rh: add connection in-memory (55dda67d-1e00-4684-9280-909c6ee400f9,"mywifirouter 3")
Feb 14 14:18:31 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171911.7881] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'mywifirouter 3' (55dda67d-1e00-4684-9280-909c6ee400f9)
Feb 14 14:18:31 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171911.8045] settings-connection[0x78e378,55dda67d-1e00-4684-9280-909c6ee400f9]: write: successfully commited (ifcfg-rh: persist (null))
Feb 14 14:18:31 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171911.8051] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="55dda67d-1e00-4684-9280-909c6ee400f9" name="mywifirouter 3" pid=829 uid=0 result="success"
Feb 14 14:18:31 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171911.8311] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.3518] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to B8:27:EB:4E:21:31 (preserve)
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4138] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4170] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'mywifirouter 3' has security, but secrets are required.
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4173] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4197] sup-iface[0x75c728,wlan0]: wps: type pbc start...
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4489] device (wlan0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4538] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4569] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'mywifirouter 3' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4573] Config: added 'ssid' value 'mywifirouter'
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4574] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4575] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4577] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4578] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.4579] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Feb 14 14:18:32 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171912.5643] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb 14 14:18:35 rp3-f3 wpa_supplicant[628]: wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'mywifirouter'
Feb 14 14:18:35 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171915.8830] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Feb 14 14:18:39 rp3-f3 wpa_supplicant[628]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 status_code=16
Feb 14 14:18:39 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171919.5527] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Feb 14 14:18:39 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171919.6531] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb 14 14:18:42 rp3-f3 wpa_supplicant[628]: wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'mywifirouter'
Feb 14 14:18:42 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171922.8896] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Feb 14 14:18:46 rp3-f3 wpa_supplicant[628]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 status_code=16
Feb 14 14:18:46 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171926.4180] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Feb 14 14:18:46 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171926.9547] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb 14 14:18:50 rp3-f3 wpa_supplicant[628]: wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'mywifirouter'
Feb 14 14:18:50 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171930.2365] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Feb 14 14:18:53 rp3-f3 wpa_supplicant[628]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 status_code=16
Feb 14 14:18:53 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171933.7849] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Feb 14 14:18:54 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171934.8220] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb 14 14:18:57 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <warn>  [1550171937.6659] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Feb 14 14:18:57 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171937.6661] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 14 14:18:57 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <info>  [1550171937.6699] sup-iface[0x75c728,wlan0]: wps: type pbc start...
Feb 14 14:18:57 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <warn>  [1550171937.6795] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Feb 14 14:18:57 rp3-f3 NetworkManager[554]: <warn>  [1550171937.6858] device (wlan0): No agents were available for this request.
Feb 14 14:18:57 rp3-f3 wpa_supplicant[628]: wlan0: WPS-PBC-ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been caused by manually installing 2 broadcom drivers that are now included with Fedora 29.  After removing those steps from my custom SD card formatter script, wifi works fine.  Thanks for the suggestions, I'll keep those in mind for future problems

Answer (score 0):

On your router, changed 802.11n Mode to Mixed or Off. based on the answer to this question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/630306/

Or, try running `killall wpa_supplicant`, based on the solution to this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+bug/1311257

Please comment, let us know which one worked, if either.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I added the answer below - basically I used an old installation process and accidentally used the wrong drivers.